# Menus panel in wordpress customizer

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove Menus panel in wordpress customizer using below code but its not working.Someone please guide me.Thanks

```
$wp_customize->remove_panel( 'nav_menus' );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 Trac tickets that govern this issue. The complete solution to this is

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( $wp_customize ) {
        /** @var WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize */
        remove_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_register', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'customize_register' ), 11 );
        remove_filter( 'customize_dynamic_setting_args', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'filter_dynamic_setting_args' ) );
        remove_filter( 'customize_dynamic_setting_class', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'filter_dynamic_setting_class' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'print_templates' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'available_items_template' ) );
        remove_action( 'customize_preview_init', array( $wp_customize->nav_menus, 'customize_preview_init' ) );
}, 10 );
```

More details:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33552

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33411

In the old versions of wordpress (<4.3) this worked, but not now:

```
function your_customizer( $wp_customize ) {
$wp_customize->remove_panel( 'widgets' );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'your_customizer' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [dingo_d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629127/dingo-d), that worked for me too.
Incidentally, `$wp_customize->remove_panel('widgets);` still works in Wordpress v. 4.5.1